# How to hide or disable angular button, once user click the button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angular I have servicenow experience, I need one help in incident form I have one angular button (**Create this incident**)  once user click the button that button should be hide or read only any code help
code :

```
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$root.trigger()">Create this ticket</button>
  <hr/>
  <h3 class="show-font"><b>OPTIONAL INFORMATION</b></h3>

  <!--<p class="text-muted small">This will help us understand who should be looking into your ticket.</p>-->
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use the `*ngIf` directive: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-ojiadv)

create one variable make it default true;

```
isShow=true;
```

give button if condition in element

```
ng-if="isShow"
```

when you clickked give click function to html `ng-click="test()"`

change it

```
test(){
   this.isShow=!this.isShow;
}
```